# Mezzanine - How make a user access only blog features in admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, mezzanine

I'm creating a simple site using Mezzanine and I like give users some permissions, like blog permission (add, edit and remove post). I've created a user and added all blog permissions to him, however, as this user isn't an admin, I've unchecked "superuser status" checkbox. I was expecting that the user could access only the blog sections of the admin page, instead of this, the user receives the message:

> You don't have permission to access the admin of this page.

Is there a way I can permit to a user the access only to the blog's admin?

Comment: You have to make the user 'staff'

Comment: I've already marked the staff checkbox... without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to marking the user as staff, you also have to enable the site for that user (lower on the user admin page).  If the site isn't listed, you can add it with the green plus.  It has to be selected (gray) for this to work.  It isn't obvious that this is how this is done.
[image: Staff Status]

[image: Site Permissions]